# Sencha Touch 2: Ext.Map control show event will not fire

Tags: javascript, dictionary, sencha-touch-2

I have a control in which I have extended an 'Ext.Map'. Everything works fine and it loads fine, using my current location.

The thing that does not work is the 'show' event is never fired. I have tried overloading it in a controller:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Map', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        refs: {
            myMap: 'myMap'
        },
        control: {
            myMap: {
                show: 'onMyMapShow'
            }
        }
    },

    onMyMapShow: function(myMap, eOpts) {
        // never enters this function...
    }
});
```

...as well as in the control itself:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyMap', {
    extend: 'Ext.Map',
    xtype: 'myMap',

    config: {
        layout: 'fit',
        useCurrentLocation: true,

        listeners: {
            show: function() {
                // never enters this function either...
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Nothing seems to work. How do I get the show event to fire? When is it expected to fire?

Answer (score 0):

That is because the `show` event is not fired when the `show()` function is called.

If you want to execute some code when your map is shown then you need to listen to the `maprender` or `painted` event.

Hope this helped.